# What difficulties could be there in establishing automatic checks for SO cross-posts on a site like our (50-100 questions a day)?

Tags: support, cross-posting

The automatic check I would like to learn about looks like as follows:

For every `question` posted (alternatively: voted to close or pushed to close queue),

1. Check if asker has linked SO account
2. If yes, check 3 of their most recent questions at SO
3. For every of above 3 questions, calculate [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of its text to that of to Programmers `question`.
4. Raise system flag for mod attention (or [present blocking message](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/what-difficulties-could-be-there-in-establishing-automatic-checks-for-so-cross-p?noredirect=1#comment17959_6660)) if distance for a particular question is less than some `threshold`.

What difficulties could be there in getting above check done automatically?

<sup>`threshold` mentioned above can be derived based on a representative set of already identified cross-posts. This set (**few hundreds** in last half year), in turn, can be retrieved by searching flag database for my flags that are marked helpful and have message containing `http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info`.</sup>

---

- Side note (as this has been asked twice in comments). I am somewhat skeptical on *blocking message* approach. In theory, this would be ideal solution but I am concerned that if presented with block, some users will try to trick to break through Levenshtein threshold (for example, by adding dots to question text). This may return us back to having to discover them manually. My considerations are similar to those why question ban / serial voting algorithms are not exposed for "direct user testing"

Comment: To preemptively address possible comments like _oh but system flags will increase moderators load_ - no it won't. Cross-posts are identified and flagged (just as suggested at [MSE tag wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)) and moderators handle them anyway, the only difference would be that flags would raise automatically instead of manually.

Comment: Better yet prevent the user from posting the duplicate and tell them to either flag the original question for migration or delete and repost.

Comment: @ChrisF I am somewhat skeptical on that. In theory, this would be ideal solution but I am concerned that if presented with block, some users will try to trick to break through Levenshtein threshold (for example, by adding dots to question text). This may return us back to having to discover them manually. My considerations are similar to those why question ban / serial voting algorithms are not exposed for "direct user testing". Anyway, I added your option into the question, let developers consider options

Comment: That's a good point. Extending it to a block was my initial reaction to your idea - if there are good reasons why that wouldn't be a good idea then I'm happy to withdraw the suggestion.

Comment: This would be excellent, but why a flag? I think a message notifying the OP that there's little value in cross-posting would be good enough. Also #2 should be "If yes, check their last 3 _open_ questions at SO". Lastly, why isn't this a feature request?

Comment: @YannisRizos see my [prior comment](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/what-difficulties-could-be-there-in-establishing-automatic-checks-for-so-cross-p?noredirect=1#comment17960_6660) :) "I am somewhat skeptical on that. In theory, this would be ideal solution but I am concerned..."

Comment: Oh come on, you can't expect me to read existing comments before I post my own @gnat ;P

Comment: There _is_ a check to see if a duplicate exists on a destination site which rejects a migration if so, but ... I am _not_ promising anything here beyond that I'll look into it.

Comment: @TimPost thanks! your insight helped me figure a new, better feature request: [Perform automatic checks for cross-posting and question ban at SO when post enters close queue, not only at attempt to migrate](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6795/31260). I voted to close this as a dupe of new request as it seems to better cover what I want