# What would be the reasons to comment on a question instead of voting to close it?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

I notice that gnat often comments on questions explaining why they would probably be closed, writing comments [such as](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/251960/align-data-horizontally-phpexcel#comment505810_251960):

> why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

without voting to close.

What would be the reasons to do that? Is this related to a maximum number of questions a person can close per day?

Comment: You _are_ aware of the daily vote limits, I assume?

Comment: @Oded: I do, that's why I specified it as a possible reason in my question. But I'm not sure if there are others.

Comment: gnat is the only one who can authoritatively answer this, but my guess is that he is usually out of close-votes when you see that behaviour.

Comment: **Not** a duplicate, but closely related: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6507/provide-10k-users-more-close-votes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a straightforward question I tend to ask when I can't figure why something was posted at Programmers instead of Stack Overflow. I expect askers to read my comment at a face value:

#### "why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow?"

Second part of my comment is a reference to MSE post that provides a fairly detailed guidance on this matter: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)

I add it to make sure that asker understands what is my take on the matter and will help me understand their reasons for posting here according to mentioned guidance:

> #### [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
>
> Implementation problems, and questions on software tools commonly used by programmers. If your code or your IDE doesn't work, ask on Stack Overflow.
>
> Does not welcome subjective questions (anymore).
>
> #### [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
>
> The main focus is whiteboard questions, problems that you face while in front of your whiteboard designing your project. Everything that can be considered part of the [SDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life-cycle), except implementation.
>
> Also, questions on freelancing and business concerns that require the unique expertise of software developers. We use this lovely diagram to help people understand if their questions belong on Programmers:
>
> [image: And somehow people still don't get it]
>
> If your questions fall in the "all careers" circle, you should ask them on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions).
>
> Programmers welcomes some subjective questions, but they should still be suitable for the Q&A format. No polls, no lists, no product recommendations, no discussions...

As for close votes, no, it doesn't depend on whether I am out of or short on these. What it really depends on is whether asker appears to have a reasonably solid presence on Stack Overflow or not (I check their profile prior to asking).

I abstain of asking someone who doesn't have SO account or is registered there only recently, assuming that they most likely just don't know. I also don't ask if it turns out that question has been cross-posted ([seems to happen rather frequently](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/what-difficulties-could-be-there-in-establishing-automatic-checks-for-so-cross-p)).

Answer (score 1):

There is a finite limit to the number of close votes that you can cast in one day. Gnat, being the ever watchful guardian that he is, often runs out of those particularly early in the morning, or he may feel that the question is ripe for mod-closing, or even deletion, and may be playing it safe with his votes in an attempt to make them as useful as possible.

Comment: As a follow up, that question did self-delete once explained that cross posting was frowned upon and that P.SE wasn't the right place for the question, saving gnat a CV.